# EXCEL VBA - Select Case - Index / Match

Tags: excel, match, case, vba

I have a spreadsheet which contains a massive IF then Formula and it's getting a bit out of control, the spreadsheet is getting slower and becoming more difficult to maintain.

Is it possible to move the formulas from the cells to VBA? Would this have any improvement on performance? I was thinking about using a Select Case but need some help as to whether a select case would work.  
The select case will need to look at multiple cells **i.e.** `If A1 = Yes AND A2 = "Cash" AND A3 = No"` then call the Index Match function to retrieve the value.  Is this possible?

Is there a big performance gain moving formula's out of the worksheet into VBA?

Thanks for any advice.
Brett

Comment: If what your saying is to process the comparison background and just output the result in the cell, VBA would certainly improve it. But if what your saying is to create a custom function utilizing *Select Case statement* within the function, I don't think so. But, if you could somehow show an example of your formula which you wish to improve, there might be some other way? It's hard to tell without seeing what you currently have.

Comment: Can I post an example spreadsheet on here? Or can I e-mail it across?

Comment: If you have no legal issues in doing that it's fine. You can upload it in any free file sharing website then post the link here. But if it is only the *IF* formula, then just post an example. I guess that's easier rather than uploading the whole WB. And besides, you'll receive better answers if your question is specific and not too broad.

Comment: Here is a really rough example of the formula which would be needed in VBA.  =IF(AND(C3="APPLE",D3="ENGLAND"),INDEX(APPLE_TODAY_ENGLAND,MATCH(B3,APPLE_FARM_ENGLAND,0)),IF(AND(C3="APPLE",D3="SPAIN"),INDEX(APPLE_TODAY_SPAIN,MATCH(B3,APPLE_FARM_SPAIN,0)),IF(AND(C3="STRAWBERRY",D3="ENGLAND"),INDEX(STRAWBERRY_TODAY_ENGLAND,MATCH(B3,STRAWBERRY_FARM_ENGLAND,0)),INDEX(STRAWBERRY_TODAY_FRANCE,MATCH(B3,STRAWBERRY_FARM_FRANCE,0)))))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you find any performance improvement simply from moving the same code from the cell into VBA.

However it will be easier to read, and you may then see that not all of the conditionals are necessary, so you may be able to simplify it - which would speed it up.

"Select Case" will probably not be helpful though as it can only be used for a single comparison, not three like you mention.

I would suggest taking it one step at a time, move the formula into VBA, and convert it to a VBA "if" statement.  Then you may be able to see ways to tidy it up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.
The main advantage to using VBA is that you could then also use *for* or *while* loops.
So instead of writing the same formula for each cell, you can develop your code to do these calculations in as many cells as you need/want.

Its not an easy question to answer, due to the little amount of information provided in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I will take another look at the formula to see if I can make any improvement.  I am not really clear how I enter the IF / index match formula into VBA, would you be able to provide an example? I need to the formula to run on any changes to the data.  So for example if there was a change to the data where the index/match was looking it would automatically update without running a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Having the code in Excel formulas mean that it will be recalculated when any of its parameters changes i.e. you change the value of one Excel cell -> all Excel cells that use this value will be recalculated. This may significantly slow down Excel when you are making constant changes.

**One way** of handling this is to manually turn off Automatic calculations (Formulas->Calculation Options->Manual). Make your changes and run the calculations manually by hitting Formulas->Calculate Now for recalculating the whole workbook or Formulas->Calculate Sheet for a recalc of only the worksheet.

**Another way** is to move the formulas to a VBA procedure. This way you can execute the calculation manually while all the other calculations in the workbook are carried out automatically.

EDIT1:
To make an VBA procedure from an Excel formula create a procedure like this:

```
    Sub CalculateFormula
        Range("A1").Value = Evaluate("YOUR EXCEL FORMULA WITHOUT '='")
        'Simple example below
        Range("A1").Value = Evaluate("IF(A1=1,1,2)")
    End Sub
```

EDIT2:
With looping:

```
Sub CalculateFormula
    for i = 1 to 10
        Range("A" & i).Value = Evaluate("IF(B" & i &  "=""Hello"",2,1)")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: We really need the spreadsheet updating in real time so it's difficult to turn the calculations to manual.  When the spreadsheet is open the performance is ok, it's just if any changes are request it's becoming difficult to administer. Do you have an example of the VBA code, this is the part I am struggling with? I need to create a formula in excel to handle an if index/match else index/match.

Comment: If you have the formula ready simply copy it into vba using the eval function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand:

Comment: A dummy formula which I would like to put into VBA to see how it works is below:  =IF(AND(C3="APPLE",D3="ENGLAND"),INDEX(APPLE_TODAY_ENGLAND,MATCH(B3,APPLE_FARM_ENGLAND,0)),IF(AND(C3="APPLE",D3="SPAIN"),INDEX(APPLE_TODAY_SPAIN,MATCH(B3,APPLE_FARM_SPAIN,0)),IF(AND(C3="STRAWBERRY",D3="ENGLAND"),INDEX(STRAWBERRY_TODAY_ENGLAND,MATCH(B3,STRAWBERRY_FARM_ENGLAND,0)),INDEX(STRAWBERRY_TODAY_FRANCE,MATCH(B3,STRAWBERRY_FARM_FRANCE,0)))))

Comment: E.g. VBA procedure:
Sub Cal() 
Range("A1").Value = Evaluate("IF(AND(C3....") 'Your Excel formula here
End Sub

Copy the procedure to your VBA project and replace the A1 in Range("A1") with the actual current cell address of your Excel formula in Excel

Comment: Thanks, it gives me an error, guess it's something to do with the "" I tried Range("H3").Value = Evaluate("IF(AND(C9="APPLE",D9="ENGLAND"),INDEX(APPLE_TODAY_ENGLAND,MATCH(B9,APPLE_FARM_ENGLAND,0)),IF(AND(C9="APPLE",D9="SPAIN"),INDEX(APPLE_TODAY_SPAIN,MATCH(B9,APPLE_FARM_SPAIN,0)),IF(AND(C9="STRAWBERRY",D9="ENGLAND"),INDEX(STRAWBERRY_TODAY_ENGLAND,MATCH(B9,STRAWBERRY_FARM_ENGLAND,0)),INDEX(STRAWBERRY_TODAY_FRANCE,MATCH(B9,STRAWBERRY_FARM_FRANCE,0)))))")

Comment: Replace " with "" in the Evaluate function. Meaning all " brackets must be proceeded with ". E.g.  Evaluate("IF(A1=""Hello"",2,1)") instead of Evaluate("IF(A1="Hello",2,1)")

Comment: Thanks, if I want to apply this formula to a range of cells i.e. Range("A1:A10").Value = Evaluate("IF(b1=""Hello"",2,1)"),I would need the A2 value looking to see if b2 = "Hello".

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Do you think it's worth putting this into VBA, considering the example formula above. I am not sure how much benefit this is going to give me, other than being easier to read.

Comment: If you consider that it's slowing Excel down then - yes it's worth it. If there is no performance setback ten I would stick with the Excel formula - it is always best to avoid VBA when possible.